# JBPM Swagger UI and my REST services produces 403 (Forbidden) on remote calls on JBoss EAP 7.3.0 with JBPM 7.44

Tags: rest, jboss, swagger, jbpm

I recently moved from developing JBPM on my local machine to hosting my code on another machine and am trying to get it to work for the first time.  The machine has JBoss 7.3.0 installed and I installed Business Central, KieServer and my custom code to the machine.  The KieServer Swagger UI comes up (http://localhost:8080/kie-server/docs/#/) but even the simplest (no parameter) calls in the UI produce a 403 (Forbidden) error.

This seems to be the relevant configuration from my standalone-full.xml.  I am binding to 0.0.0.0 to get this to run and will restrict it once my code is running.  What do I need to change to get the Swagger UI to call JBPM via REST?  I assume I need to get this to run to get *my* REST calls to run!

I think we only use basic authentication on the server - it is not yet tied into Keycloak and my manager's manager gave me the keystore he made....so I am using a username/password I installed with the JBOSS CLI (add-user).

```
       <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.webservices.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:4.0"/>
    </profile>
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
        <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="dummy.smtp.com" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the user created in the CLI needed some of the JBPM roles mapped to him.